# How we configurate cable.yml (Action Cable) using postgresql?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-6

I try to configure the cable.yml like this
*development:
adapter: postgresql
test:
adapter: postgresql
production:
adapter: postgresql
url: ?
channel_prefix:  ?*

Answer (score 0):

it's better if you can use a cache service like redis https://redis.io/ for better performance as you'll be roughly hitting the db with the notification system for each user with an always-open socket.

But you can configure your yml file as follow:

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql

test:
  adapter: postgresql

staging:
  adapter: postgresql

production:
  adapter: postgresql
  url: production_db_url
  channel_prefix:
```

see the documentation at this specific part where it mentions redis in production at least for the same reason I mentioned before :
https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_cable_overview.html#subscription-adapter